# Can someone explain this really basic Python code to me?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

Recently, I went to a job interview for a Python developer position. The following code was one of the questions. I just had to write the output.

```
def extendList(val,list=[]):
    list.append(val)
    return list

list1 = extendList(10)
list2 = extendList(123,[])
list3 = extendList('a')

print "list1 = %s " %list1
print "list2 = %s " %list2
print "list2 = %s " %list3
```

The output is:

```
list1 = [10, 'a'] 
list2 = [123] 
list2 = [10, 'a']
```

I'm trying to understand why the first list, `list1`, has the `'a'` value.

**EDIT**

I checked all the links and found out its a python "gotcha" for begginers, but want to thank the answers, can´t choose both so i´m going with the first one.

Comment: [This canonical answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument) should help

Comment: I would say it is a dupe, because this question or any answers are not likely to benefit future users. It is a known Python "gotcha!" and future readers should be redirected to the existing explanation.

Comment: @AdamSmith it is a duplicate because the answer is basically `the default argument is mutable`. It does not have to be the exact same question. There is nothing that can be added here that is a/ not in the other question and b/ reusable by someone else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`list1` has `'a'` because the list created with `extendlist('a')` is appending to the same list as `extendList(10)`

This is no doubt the result of particulars in the way Python deals with default arguments and it's state model.  You could even argue this is a bug, because it violates the closure property (if Python's methods are supposed to be closures).

For example the equivalent code in Ruby:

```
def extendList(val, list=[])
  list << val
  return list
end
```

returns

```
extendList(10)
# => [10]

extendList(123, [])
# => [123]

extendList('a') 
# => ['a']
```

This is the case in Ruby because Ruby methods are closures, that is, each method invocation carries around it's own local environment.

Comment: . . .and the `print` doesn't happen until after all 3 `extendList`s have been evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, this isn't that basic, it's a bit of a python pitfall: [Mutable Default Parameter](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/)

Compare with printing after each function call:

```
>>> def extendList(val,list=[]):
...     list.append(val)
...     return list
...
>>> list1 = extendList(10)
>>> print "list1 = %s " %list1
list1 = [10]
>>> list2 = extendList(123,[])
>>> print "list2 = %s " %list2
list2 = [123]
>>> list3 = extendList('a')
>>> print "list2 = %s " %list3
list2 = [10, 'a']
```

Also:

```
>>> list1 is list2
False
>>> list1 is list3
True
```

Comment: see, with this code I´m not getting the 'a' in the first list. WTF. jeje